# Hibernate session factory is always null

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to use this code in Spring application and Hibernate using JNDI.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextDatasource {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.plugin.database.models" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:/global/production_gateway");
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager getHibernateTransactionManager() throws NamingException {
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor getExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        try {
            transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect");

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

When I try to use:

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
..
session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Session factory is always null. Am I'm missing some important configuration. During package deployment I don't get error messages:

```
20:15:37,217 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 178) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}
20:15:37,219 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 178) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
20:15:37,302 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 178) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
20:15:37,404 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 178) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
20:15:37,599 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 178) HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.
20:15:38,186 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 178) Hibernate:
```

Can you give me some advice what I'm missing?

Comment: what is the package of your `MainApplication` and `ContextDatasource`? A `SpringBootApplication` does by default a component-scan of all the sub-packages

Comment: Why do you have 2 transaction managers? Also an `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` if an `@Autowired` field cannot be satisfied your application will not even start. Hence you are probably creating an instance of the bean that needs the session factory outside the scope of spring.

Comment: This is my Spring start method: https://pastebin.com/jhhqbG1N

Comment: @M.Deinum Which transaction manager should I remove?

Comment: Either one. Also you state you use Spring Boot but none of your code shows any usage of Spring Boot (unless you are trying very hard to avoid using Spring Boot in a spring boot application).

Comment: The WAR page will be used as API server. If it's not mandatory can I use @EnableWebMvc?